# key "w" toggles though selection typs

Tags: customization

I accidentially found out that if you press the key "w" multiple times it toggles through selection types "Box-select, Circle-select, Lasso-select..."

I opened the preferences and wanted to find that behavior in the keymap. So I changed the filter-method to keybindng, typed in the letter "w" and in the result there was nothing that matched.

I have no clue where to find this behavior. Can anybody help me out?

thanks in advance
daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this in the keymap under *3D View > Set Tool By Name*. You can search for specific shortcuts by selecting *Key Binding* in the dropdown in front of the search box.

[image]

Comment: thank you, 
Do you know a way to find all build in pie-menues?

Comment: @faceless you should be able to search for "pie" and dropdown set to name. It should list all shortcuts operating on `wm.call_menu_pie`.

Comment: Great, I didn't think it would be that easy.